# Waveform Widget Touchgfx

Tags: c++, waveform

I’m creating a waveform widget in TouchGFX, but unsure how best to loop the waveform back to zero at the end because there are three frame buffers so you have to invalidate over an area three times or you get flickering . How would you handle looping the array back to start (x=0).

The main issue is my code originally assumed there was only one frame buffer. I think my code needs to be refactored for three framebuffers or add the ability to write directly to the frame buffer. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
  bool Graph::drawCanvasWidget(const Rect& invalidatedArea) const
  {
if (numPoints < 3)
{
    // A graph line with a single (or not even a single) point is invisible
    return true;
}
else{

Canvas canvas(this, invalidatedArea);   
for (int index = 0; index < (numPoints-1); index++)
{
    canvas.moveTo(points[index].x,points[index].y);
    canvas.lineTo(points[index].x,points[index+1].y);
    canvas.lineTo(points[index+1].x,points[index+1].y);
    canvas.lineTo(points[index+1].x,points[index].y);       
}
return canvas.render(); // Shape above automatically closed
}
return true;
  }

  void Graph::newPoint(int y)
  {
    if(numPoints==501){
        numPoints=0;
    }else if ((maxPoints-numPoints)<=20){
    points[numPoints].x = numPoints;
    points[numPoints].y = y;
    Rect minimalRect(480,0,20,100);
    invalidateRect(minimalRect);            
    numPoints++;
    }else{
    points[numPoints].x = numPoints;
    points[numPoints].y = y;
    Rect minimalRect(numPoints-3,0,20,100);
    invalidateRect(minimalRect);
    numPoints++;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With TouchGFX 4.15.0 (just out) the TouchGFX Designer now supports a Graph widget (previously only found in source code in demos) which can be used to produce your waveforms. It has some more elegant ways of inserting points which may suit your needs.